# What does the parameter -1 in numpy shape[::-1] mean?

Tags: python, numpy

What does the parameter -1 in numpy shape[::-1] mean?

```
template = cv2.imread('template.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, it has nothing to do with numpy. You are accessing a tuple with [start:end:step] (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) for more details), using a step of -1 means you reverse the order.

Comment: If I don't use -1 my code will be  `h, w = template.shape[::-1]`?

Comment: If it is a 2D matrix, then it would be `h, w = template.shape`.